# jQuery - checking if there are duplicated paired values in a table form

Tags: jquery, html-table, duplicates

I have a form like this :

```
<form>
<table id="table1">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="val1" name="code[1][data1]" value="abc" /></td>//this need to be check
<td><input type="text" id="val2" name="code[1][data2]" value="def" /></td>//this need to be check
<td><input type="text" name="code[1][data3]" value="xxx" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="code[1][data4]" value="xxx" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="val1" name="code[2][data1]" value="abc" /></td>//this is the duplicated value
<td><input type="text" id="val2" name="code[2][data2]" value="jkl" /></td>//this is the duplicated value
<td><input type="text" name="code[2][data3]" value="xxx" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="code[2][data4]" value="xxx" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="val1" name="code[3][data1]" value="abc" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="val2" name="code[3][data2]" value="def" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="code[3][data3]" value="xxx" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="code[3][data4]" value="xxx" /></td>
</tr>
....
</table>

<p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save Changes"  /></p>
</from>
```

How can I check the duplicated values in the table upon submit? The elements that need to test is the first 2 td input value of each row.

From the example above, the values of `code[1][data1]&&code[1][data2]` in the first row should not same as  `code[3][data1]&&code[3][data2]` in the 3rd row.

Comment: You should first validate your markup, IDs must be unique.

Comment: Is there any other way?Using the name instead of ID? Because it is a dynamic form, where each row is created by an ajax call..

Comment: Yes, you can use `class` or `data-*` attributes.

Comment: any example how to do it in jquery?

Comment: JavaScript should not be used for fixing the markup, you should fix the code that generate your form.